# Winform doesn't recognize Dataset created in VC# designer

Tags: c#

I have created a dataset with the C# designer following this tutorial http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28678/1954 ; When I drag and drop a datable on a form and run the program it says it says the type name XMLDB doesn't exist in the type XMLDB.XMLDB on line

```
this.XMLDB = new XMLDB.XMLDB();
```

Why ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, having a conflicting property **and** namespace **and** class name is usually a big warning sign (or 3, in this case); the first thing I'd try is fixing the names to be unambiguous;

```
this.DB = new SomeNamespace.XmlDB();
```

Comment: Thanks I created a new project and a new dataset with 2 different names then it works (but seems illogical to me that this creates a conflict as it was created automatically by the Designer).